# how to replace a selected text in a TextBox with a string?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I want to replace the selected text in a TextBox with another string in c# . I am using the following code but it replaces all the same texts in all the TextBox (not only my selected text). How may I solve this?

```
string selectedTxt = TextBox1.SelectedText;
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(selectedTxt, "<b>" + selectedTxt + "</b>");
```

Comment: What is the type of your project? Winforms? WPF? Or ...?

Comment: Yes it is windows form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to replace, just set the `SelectedText` property with new text. Explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext?view=netcore-3.1)

```
string selectedTxt = TextBox1.SelectedText;
TextBox1.SelectedText = "<b>" + selectedTxt + "</b>";
```